# Finding a subgraph with smaller clique number without removing a clique the size of the clique number.

Tags: graph-theory

Given an infinite graph $G$, with clique number $2< \omega (G) < \infty$, is it possible to remove vertices such that the remaining subgraph has clique number $\omega (G)-1$, under the restriction that you cannot remove a clique of size $\omega (G)$?

Comment: I'm specifying an infinite graph because it would prove it in the finite case as well.  I guess it is just more general, but yes I am assuming $\omega (G)$ is finite.

Comment: Does the restriction "you cannot remove a clique of size $\omega(G)$" simply mean that the induced subgraph of $G$ on the set of **removed** vertices does not contain a clique of size $\omega(G)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me restate the question:

> Let $2\lt k\lt\infty.$ Given a (finite) graph $G=(V,E)$ with clique number $\omega(G)=k,$ can we find a vertex partition $V=V_1\cup V_2$ such that the induced subgraphs $G[V_1]$ and $G[V_2]$ both have clique number less than $k$?

(There is no loss of generality in restricting our attention to finite graphs, because, by a slight generalization of the [De Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)), an infinite graph $G$ will admit such a partition if each of its finite subgraphs does. This can be proved by the usual "compactness argument" using an [ultrafilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) or the [Tychonoff product theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem) or the [compactness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) of first-order logic.)

For $k=2$ the answer would be negative, as shown by the example $G=C_5.$ In fact, the answer is negative for all values of $k,$ but the counterexamples for $k\gt2$ are not so simple. I will use the following result of [Jon Folkman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Folkman) [Graphs with monochromatic complete subgraphs in every edge coloring, SIAM J. Appl. Math. 18 (1970), 19-24 ] which was later generalized by the [Nešetřil–Rödl theorem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895676900150):

> **Folkman's Theorem.** For each positive integer $k$ there is a graph $G_k$, with clique number $\omega(G_k)=k$, such that every coloring of the edges of $G_k$ with two colors contains a monochromatic $K_k$.

Suppose $k\gt2.$ Consider Folkman's graph $G_k=G=(V,E),$ and consider any partition of the vertex-set $V$ into two disjoint subsets $V_1,V_2.$ Color an edge of $G$ red if it has one endpoint in $V_1$ and the other in $V_2$; otherwise color it blue. Then $G$ contains a monochromatic $K_k$. But a red $K_k$ is impossible for $k\gt2.$ Thus $G$ contains a blue $K_k,$ that is, a $K_k$ whose vertices all lie on the same side of the partition. In other words, either $\omega(G[V_1])=k$ or else $\omega(G[V_2])=k.$

Comment: That was rather elegant.